# How to mock an API call with Jest (Amplify API)

Tags: typescript, rest, mocking, aws-amplify, ts-jest

I am currently working on a project using AWS Amplify API.
I am trying to test a Component in which I am doing a post API call (in the checkCredentials method), but would like to mock it in order to test my component's behavior, not the API call.

Here is my component:

```
const LoginPage = () => {
    const [{username, password}, updateCredentials] = React.useState({username: '', password: ''})
    const [errorMsg, setMsg] = useState('');
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    let invalidLoginMessage = errorMsg

    const checkCredentials = async (event: React.FormEvent) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        try {
            const loginData = await API.post('api', '/login/', {body: {username: username, password: password} })
            if (loginData.message === 'Login Successful'){
                console.log(loginData)
                authStatus.handleLogin(username);
                navigate("/home");
            }
        } catch (err) {console.log('Login Error', {err})} {setMsg("Informations invalides! Merci d'utiliser une adresse @ingeno.ca.")}    
    }

    return(
        <div className="withPadding">
            <form onSubmit={checkCredentials}>
                <div>Merci de vous authentifier afin d'utiliser l'application!</div>
                <label htmlFor="username">Nom d'utilisateur</label>
                <input placeholder='E-mail' data-testid="usernameInput" id="user" value={username} onChange={(event) => updateCredentials({
                    username: event.target.value,
                    password
                })} />
                <label htmlFor="password">Mot de passe</label>
                <input placeholder='Password' data-testid="passwordInput" id="password" type="password" value = {password} onChange={(event) => updateCredentials({
                    username,
                    password: event.target.value,
                })} />
                <Button data-testid="boutonLogin" type = "submit" className="btn-sm">Se connecter</Button>
                <br />
                <h4 style={{ color: 'red' }}>{invalidLoginMessage}</h4>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And here is my current test:

```
it('should show "invalid credentials" message when invalid credentials', () => {
      render(
        <Router>
          <LoginPage />
        </Router>)

      API.post = jest.fn().mockImplementation( () => { 
          return JSON.parse('{ "message": "Login Error"}')
      });

      const message = screen.getByText(errorMessage)
      const usernameInput = screen.getByPlaceholderText("E-mail")
      const passwordInput = screen.getByPlaceholderText("Password")
      fireEvent.change(usernameInput, {target: {value: invalidTestUser}})
      fireEvent.change(passwordInput, {target: {value: password}})
      userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId("boutonLogin"))

      expect((usernameInput as HTMLInputElement).value).toBe("testusername")
      expect((passwordInput as HTMLInputElement).value).toBe("12345")
      expect(message).toBeInTheDocument();
   })
```

I am getting the following error :

```
 TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: Informations invalides! Merci d'utiliser une adresse @ingeno.ca.. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.
```

Now I was wondering if my API mock was adequate and if not how would one manage to do such a thing using an AWS Amplify API? I find it hard to know if the test fails because the mock is bad or if the page doesn't update in time for the text to appear.

**EDIT**

I tried some things out and am pretty sure that my API call mock is the reason why my test isn't passing. By creating a similar method without the API call, the test passes without issue, so the text is appearing. I am still unsure on how to mock the API call though.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out for my application.

```
jest.mock('aws-amplify');

const A_SUCCESS_RESPONSE = { response: 'ok' };
const AN_ERROR_RESPONSE = { response: 'something went wrong' };
const GOOD_USER_NAME = 'good-user-name';
const GOOD_PASSWORD = 'good-password';

it('success example', async () => {
    mocked(API.post).mockResolvedValue(A_SUCCESS_RESPONSE);

    const response = await API.post('api', '/login/', { body: { username: GOOD_USER_NAME, password: GOOD_PASSWORD } });

    expect(response).toEqual(A_SUCCESS_RESPONSE);
});

it('error example', async () => {
    mocked(API.post).mockRejectedValue(AN_ERROR_RESPONSE);
    try {
        await API.post('api', '/login/', { body: { username: GOOD_USER_NAME, password: GOOD_PASSWORD } });
    } catch (error) {
        expect(error).toEqual(AN_ERROR_RESPONSE);
    }
});
```

You need to mock the aws-amplify module first, then using mocked you can mock a resolved or rejected value for a specific request to test your component.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the LoginPage is still using the real API

I usually do something like

```js
// Mock the library before importing it, 
// and before importing Component Under Test

jest.mock('API');

import API from 'api';
import {mocked} from "ts-jest/utils";

const mockAPI = mocked(API);

mockAPI.post.mockImplementation( () => { 
    return JSON.parse('{ "message": "Login Error"}')
});
```